# Automatically resizing brackets

Tags: amsmath, brackets

Using amsmath, is there a command I could add in my preamble so that brackets automatically resize as appropriate?

I would like to be able to type `(` and `)` and for this to do the same as `\left(` and `\right)`. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option that automatically adjusts the size of parentheses, brackets or keys within the mathematical environment. What we do have are different size options to choose from so that the size of the parentheses is correct.

Comment: in most cases it is best to avoid `\left\right` and use fixed sizes such as `(` or `\bigl(`  for example you would never want `\left(x\right)` as left-right makes a mathinner with additional horizontal space